# Assign Projection to multiple shapefile

Tags: coordinate-system

I have multiple shape files in a folder. I want to assign projection to all the files inside the folder at one go. In batch file i am able to assign projection to all the shapefiles, but i want to select the assign projection to that folder so that all the files get projected.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please specify which software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The projection is defined in the .prj file of a shapefile dataset. This is always individually, and not valid for a whole folder of shapefiles.

What you can do is set one shapefile's .prj file correctly, then copy that .prj file to the name of all other .shp files in the folder.

Please note that this is **not** a valid reprojection. Only the CRS definition is exchanged, but no coordinate will be transformed from one CRS to another. In most cases, assigning another projection will lead to wrong coordinates (unless they were wrong before).